# Why 'bool' object is not callable?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, boolean, boolean-operations

So, I'm trying to create a script with Python to open online classes automatically.
This is my code:

```
import webbrowser
import datetime
import time

now = time.strftime("%D, %H:%M")

lesson1 = "03/09/21, 14:10"
lesson2 = "03/10/21, 14:11"
lesson3 = "03/10/21, 14:12"

while True (now != lesson1 and now != lesson2 and now != lesson3):
    print ("Waiting, the current time is " + now)
    now = time.strftime("%D, %H:%M")
    time.sleep(1)
    if (now == lesson1):
        print ("LESSON IS OPENING :D")
        webbrowser.open("https://google.com")
        while (now != "12:00"):
            time.sleep()

    if (now == lesson2):
        print ("LESSON IS OPENING :D")
        webbrowser.open("https://google.com")

    if (now == lesson3):
        print ("LESSON IS OPENING :D")
        webbrowser.open("https://google.com")
```

When I try to run the script I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matteo/Desktop/Python Project/automatic.py", line 11, in <module>
    while True (now != lesson1 and now != lesson2 and now != lesson3):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
[Finished in 0.053s]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `True (now != lesson1 and now != lesson2 and now != lesson3)` is considered as calling a method `True` with the arguments in the brackets so that's why you get the error. what are you trying to add as the condition?

Comment: You have `while True (...)`. I think you'd want to remove the `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the condition you want is rather

```
while now != lesson1 and now != lesson2 and now != lesson3:
```

`True (now != lesson1 and now != lesson2 and now != lesson3)` is considered as a function call to `True` which is not a callable, yet a boolean value.

Also, I think you might want to move the three `if`s after the `while` loop, so that only once the `while` terminates the time is checked between the three possible values.